# Removing or Hiding elments after the user change options in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

one of the features I have on my website is that the user can sort the images based on `title` and number of `horns`.

I have made the logic and it works perfectly, but the issue is with the **rendering** on the DOM.

IF I click on either sort with `title` or with `horns`, all images are being rendered.

Not sure what is the mistake I have done.

**Below is my code for illustration:**

**Please note**, I added the local JSON file in the place of the CSS, so just in case if anyone of you wants that.

```js
let arrayOfObjects = [];


function Images(description, horns, image_url, keyword, title) {
  this.description = description;
  this.horns = horns;
  this.image_url = image_url;
  this.keyword = keyword;
  this.title = title;
  arrayOfObjects.push(this);
}
fetch("../data/page-1.json")
  .then((results) => results.json())
  .then((data) => {
    data.forEach((val) => {
      new Images(
        val.description,
        val.horns,
        val.image_url,
        val.keyword,
        val.title
      );
    });
   
    render()

   sortByTitle()
   sortByHorn()
    filter()
  });
function sortted(a, b) {
  if (a.title < b.title) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.title > b.title) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
function sorttedByHorn(a, b) {
  if (a.horns > b.horns) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.horns < b.horns) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
function render() {

  const normalRender = document.getElementById("normalRender");
  // normalRender.innerHTML = ''
  arrayOfObjects.forEach((val) => {
    let imgEl = document.createElement("img");
    normalRender.appendChild(imgEl);
    imgEl.src = val.image_url;
  });
}


function sortByTitle() {
  let sortEl = document.getElementById('sort')
  let optionEl = document.createElement('option')
  sortEl.appendChild(optionEl)
  optionEl.textContent = 'Title'
  let copy = arrayOfObjects.slice()
  let sortedCopy = copy.sort(sortted)
  sortEl.addEventListener('change', () => {
    document.getElementById("normalRender").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("horn").style.display = "none";
    let divSorted = document.getElementById("title")
    divSorted.innerHTML = "";
    sortedCopy.forEach((val) => {
      let sortedImage = document.createElement('img')
      divSorted.appendChild(sortedImage)
      sortedImage.src = `${val.image_url}`
    })
  })
}
function sortByHorn() {
  let sortEl = document.getElementById('sort')
  let optionEl = document.createElement('option')
  sortEl.appendChild(optionEl)
  optionEl.textContent = 'Horn'
  let copy2 = arrayOfObjects.slice()
  let sortedCopy = copy2.sort(sorttedByHorn)
  console.log(sortedCopy)
  sortEl.addEventListener('change', () => {
    document.getElementById("normalRender").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("title").style.display = "none";
    // document.getElementById("filter").style.display = "none";
    let divSorted2 = document.getElementById("horn")
    divSorted2.innerHTML = "";
    sortedCopy.forEach((val) => {
      let sortedImage = document.createElement('img')
      divSorted2.appendChild(sortedImage)
      sortedImage.src = `${val.image_url}`
    })
  })
}
function filter() {
  let keywordArray = [];
  let selection = document.getElementById("selection");
  arrayOfObjects.forEach((val, idx) => {
    keywordArray.push(val.keyword);
  });
  let unique = [...new Set(keywordArray)];
  unique.forEach((val2) => {
    let optionEl = document.createElement("option");
    selection.appendChild(optionEl);
    optionEl.textContent = `${val2}`;
    optionEl.setAttribute("value", `${val2}`);
  });
  selection.addEventListener("change", () => {
    // document.getElementById("normalRender").style.display = "none";
    // document.getElementById("title").style.display = "none";
    // document.getElementById("horn").style.display = "none";
    let div = document.getElementById("filter");
    div.innerHTML = "";
    arrayOfObjects.forEach((val) => {
      if (selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].text === val.keyword) {
        let imgEl = document.createElement("img");
        div.appendChild(imgEl);
        imgEl.src = val.image_url;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
// this is the local JSON file

[
    {
        "image_url": "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_DBYF1AdFaHw/TE-f0cDQ24I/AAAAAAAACZg/l-FdTZ6M7z8/s1600/Unicorn_and_Narwhal_by_dinglehopper.jpg",
        "title": "UniWhal",
        "description": "A unicorn and a narwhal nuzzling their horns",
        "keyword": "narwhal",
        "horns": 1
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512636618879-bbe79107e9e3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=bd9460ee6d1ddbb6b1ca7be86dfc4590&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1825&q=80",
        "title": "Rhino Family",
        "description": "Mother (or father) rhino with two babies",
        "keyword": "rhino",
        "horns": 2
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://www.dhresource.com/0x0s/f2-albu-g5-M00-1A-11-rBVaI1hsIIiALxKzAAIHjSU3VkE490.jpg/wholesale-halloween-costume-prop-unicorn.jpg",
        "title": "Unicorn Head",
        "description": "Someone wearing a creepy unicorn head mask",
        "keyword": "unicorn",
        "horns": 1
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518946222227-364f22132616?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=4836a6fca62e7dce9324346bacfde085&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2534&q=80",
        "title": "UniLego",
        "description": "Lego figurine dressed in a unicorn outfit",
        "keyword": "unilego",
        "horns": 1
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/b4/61/06/b46106830b841017ea59870b27ec18dc--narwhals-a-unicorn.jpg",
        "title": "Basically a unicorn",
        "description": "A narwhal is basically a unicorn after all, right?",
        "keyword": "narwhal",
        "horns": 1
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/16/cf/2a/16cf2a0b3fd51b9bee08bb6296193b75.jpg",
        "title": "#truth",
        "description": "The truth behind narwhals",
        "keyword": "narwhal",
        "horns": 1
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://secure.img1-ag.wfcdn.com/im/17007094/resize-h800%5Ecompr-r85/3589/35892451/Baby+Rhino+Figurine.jpg",
        "title": "Baby Rhino",
        "description": "This is actually a figurine but it looks kinda real",
        "keyword": "rhino",
        "horns": 2
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/landbeforetime/images/c/c3/Cera_infobox.png/revision/latest?cb=20180422005003",
        "title": "Cera",
        "description": "Three horns but still, horns. And who doesn't like The Land Before Time?",
        "keyword": "triceratops",
        "horns": 3
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB18GwSQVXXXXaZaXXXq6xXFXXXh/Animal-Cosplay-Costume-Narwhal-Onesie-Mens-Womens-Cartoon-Whale-Pajamas.jpg",
        "title": "Narwhal costume",
        "description": "A woman wearing a blue narwhal costume",
        "keyword": "narwhal",
        "horns": 1
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://www.shopmascot.com/image/cache/mascotnew/new196-800x800.jpg",
        "title": "Rhino costume",
        "description": "Mascots have to get their costumes somewhere",
        "keyword": "rhino",
        "horns": 2
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://www.tinselbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/I-BELIEVE-IN-UNICORNS-FREE-PRINTABLE-WATERCOLOR-7-of-1.jpg",
        "title": "Believe",
        "description": "I believe in unicorns, do you?",
        "keyword": "unicorn",
        "horns": 1
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/Markhor_Schraubenziege_Capra_falconeri_Zoo_Augsburg-02.jpg/220px-Markhor_Schraubenziege_Capra_falconeri_Zoo_Augsburg-02.jpg",
        "title": "Markhor",
        "description": "These wild goats eat snakes, then secrete a foam that locals fight over for the antivemon properties -- how cool is that?",
        "keyword": "markhor",
        "horns": 2
    },
    {
        "image_url": "http://www.zooborns.com/.a/6a010535647bf3970b0223c84d5959200c-800wi",
        "title": "Baby markhor",
        "description": "Even the babies are adorable",
        "keyword": "markhor",
        "horns": 2
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558560063-931ca9822a0c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80",
        "title": "Mouflon",
        "description": "Those horns though",
        "keyword": "mouflon",
        "horns": 2
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556890077-020ec300d5db?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80",
        "title": "Addax",
        "description": "This guy is basically extinct but survives well in captivity, so they're frequently found in zoos",
        "keyword": "addax",
        "horns": 2
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://cbsnews3.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2013/03/05/5b414225-a645-11e2-a3f0-029118418759/thumbnail/620x350/2d4cf24685b45c22912e64d2004fec8d/Baby_Mouflon_Wild_Sheep.jpg",
        "title": "Baby mouflon",
        "description": "The cuteness that is a baby mouflon asleep",
        "keyword": "mouflon",
        "horns": 2
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514036783265-fba9577fc473?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
        "title": "Happy Jackson's Chameleon",
        "description": "These are really common in Hawaii",
        "keyword": "chameleon",
        "horns": 2
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://imgc.allpostersimages.com/img/print/posters/dlillc-jackson-s-chameleon_a-G-13448768-14258384.jpg",
        "title": "Serious Jackson's Chameleon",
        "description": "This one is very serious.",
        "keyword": "chameleon",
        "horns": 3
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://www.nps.gov/band/learn/nature/images/short-horned-lizard-open-mouth-18.jpg?maxwidth=650&autorotate=false",
        "title": "Horned Lizard",
        "description": "Fave food: ants",
        "keyword": "lizard",
        "horns": 100
    },
    {
        "image_url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/df/Smaug_par_David_Demaret.jpg/290px-Smaug_par_David_Demaret.jpg",
        "title": "Smaug",
        "description": "Fan illustration of Smaug from 'The Hobbit'",
        "keyword": "dragon",
        "horns": 100
    }
]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layouts.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modules.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title>jQuery-Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="selection">
    <option>Select</option>
  </select>
  <select id="sort">
    <option>
      Sort
    </option>
  </select>
  <div id="normalRender"></div>
  <div id="filter"></div>
  <div id="title"></div>
  <div id="horn"></div>
</body>
<script src="./js/app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you should remove the old images from div2. It can be done by setting the innerHTML of the div2 to an empty string. I also refactored your code to use more modern syntax and to avoid basic mistakes.

```js
const CONTAINER = document.getElementById("div1");
const API_URL = "../data/page-1.json";

class CustomImage {
  constructor(description, horns, image_url, keyword, title) {
    this.description = description;
    this.horns = horns;
    this.image_url = image_url;
    this.keyword = keyword;
    this.title = title;
  }
}

function render(images) {
  CONTAINER.innerHTML = "";
  images.forEach((image) => {
    const imgElement = document.createElement("img");
    imgElement.src = image.image_url;
    CONTAINER.appendChild(imgElement);
  });
}

async function getData(url) {
  // Eventually, you should use a try catch here
  const result = await fetch(url);
  return await result.json();
}

function initSelectElement(images) {
  const select = document.getElementById("selection");
  images.forEach((image) => {
    const optionElement = document.createElement("option");
    optionElement.textContent = `${image.keyword}`;
    optionElement.value = `${image.keyword}`;
    select.appendChild(optionElement);
  });

  select.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    render(images.filter((image) => e.target.value === image.keyword));
  });
}

async function main() {
  const data = await getData(API_URL);
  const images = data.map(
    (image) =>
      new CustomImage(
        image.description,
        image.horns,
        image.image_url,
        image.keyword,
        image.title
      )
  );
  initSelectElement(images);
  render(images);
}

main();
```

Comment: When I run that, it says that CONTAINER is null

Comment: In the HTML, add the script tag at the bottom of the body, or If you want to leave it in the head, use the "defer" keyword to load the script after the DOM loaded.

Comment: Thank you, but can you please check the same issue I have with the Dom when I do some sort. 

Please check the post again, I have edited it for better clearance.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating the image elements but on selection change you are not removing them, so on selection change not only you need to create new but also remove the previous Images

Comment: I know that I need to remove them but how to implement this? like at least a hint.

Comment: let imageDiv = document.getElementById('div2');
imageDiv.childNodes.forEach( node => imageDiv.removeChild(node));